# what is the adb command to put device in offline mode

Tags: android, adb

Is there an adb command to put the device offline?I tried following but doesn't seem to work

COMMAND:-

```
adb devices offline
```

Comment: what is the _offline mode_ and why do you want to put a device in it?

Comment: if you want to kill your device using command use this first check "adb devices" after that use this command "adb kill-server"

Comment: @AlexP. - if you do "adb devices" it shows as up `List of devices attached 128B123 offline` , device shows up as offline,thats what I mean

Comment: It is not a _device mode_ - just a device _registration status_. The `offline` status gets assigned after a communication failure. There is no `adb` command to force it. And you ignored the second part of my question.

Comment: Alex P - I need to put it in offline mode to test a recovery feature to bring it back online....if there is not adb command,how can we force a communication failure to put it in "offline" status

Comment: do we have any update here? Im also looking for this info!!

Comment: @user3508811 ,  I am really interested to know if you get any method to recover any android device which is in offline mode. Please share. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You can put a device in "offline" state by using push(or install) and reconnect commands:

1.push a file(or install a apk) to phone

```
adb -s [serial] push somefile /data/local/tmp
```

2.reconnect while push is still in progress

```
adb -s [serial] reconnect
```

SERIAL means serial number listed in the output of 'adb devices' command.

Repeat step 1 and 2, after a while, you can find this device is in offline state from output of "adb devices".

You can put this device in "device" state by using kill-server and start-server.

"reconnect" command is only supported by higher version of adb, 1.0.36 and later as far as I know.